# 'Park'ing related deadlock in FutureTask submitted to ExecutorService (in Android)

Tags: java, android, concurrency, freeze

I have code of the following form:

```
ExecutorService execSvc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
...
execSvc.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName("Wonky");

        try {
            //here is reached

            doSomethingWith(mSomeFutureTask.get());

            //here is never reached
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        ...
        }
    });
```

I also reduced `mSomeFutureTask` for testing purposes to a mere stub somewhat like this:

```
mSomeFutureTask = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object> {
    public Object call() {
       return null;
    }
});
```

But the thread 'Wonky' never returns from get().  When I pause the JVM this is the stack dump for that thread:

```
Thread [<18> Wonky] (Suspended) 
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread.parkFor(long) line: 1231 
    Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: 323    
    LockSupport.park(Object) line: 157  
    FutureTask$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).parkAndCheckInterrupt() line: 813   
    FutureTask$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: 973 
    FutureTask$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: 1282  
    FutureTask$Sync.innerGet() line: 219    
    MyOwnClass$SomeFutureTaskClass(FutureTask).get() line: 82   
    MyOwnClass$Runnable.run() line: 152 
    Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() line: 442  
    FutureTask$Sync.innerRun() line: 305    
    FutureTask.run() line: 137  
    ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) line: 1076  
    ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() line: 569   
    Thread.run() line: 856
```

I have no idea what it could be waiting for.  There is talk in another thread of a bad implementation of Park pre-JVM 6u21.

This brings up two other questions--what version of Java SDK does a given Android environment use (how to find out?) And what is the relationship between a "JVM 6u21" (is that a standard or an implementation?) and Dalvik 1.5.0, which is what my device is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably never submitted `mSomeFutureTask` to any executor, so the task is never finished, and `get()` is awaiting forever.

Comment: This was it.  mSomeFutureTask didn't seem directly submittable/executable initially because it was stored in a Future type and needed to be cast to a Runnable.